# Create a url that will ignore the first directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a link `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/user/username` how can I redirect it so that when someone accesses `www.example.com/username` they get the same thing as if they used `user`?

So these links would be the same pages:

`www.example.com/user/username/profile`-> `www.example.com/username/profile`

`www.example.com/user/username/messages` -> `www.example.com/username/messages`

`www.example.com/user/username/chats` -> `www.example.com/username/chats`

Is there something I can change in .htaccess to achieve this result?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve; you might want a PHP router with `mod_rewrite` (as often done with MVC applications) or [per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!user/).+$ user/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: do you know how I could use the username as a php variable?
For example example.com/*username* would actually show example.com/anyuser.php and use username as a variable.

Comment: Can you please create a new question with details